# How to bind multiple values? (Polymer 0.5)

Tags: polymer

Is there a formal way to bind multiple values to a template? Through trial and error, I came up with this:

```
<template bind="{{ {param1: 'value1', param2: 'value2'} as params }}" ref="myTemplate">
```

But this feels clunky. Is there a better way?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Polymer?

Comment: @tony19 Because 1.0 isn't backward compatible, so we're stuck on 0.5 for now.